# Getting Error : Exception in thread "main" while executing program for different loop conditions in static block

Tags: java, hashmap, static-block, main-method

There is no problem in program execution if i am having loop condition as little value (i.e. 1000 or 10000) in **static block**, its working. the problem is in **loop** in static block for given code. whenever i am executing below code i am getting exception **"could not find main class"**
see the below code :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class TestStatic {
static HashMap<String,Integer> testMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
   }
 static
  {
    for(int i=0; i< 10000000; i++)
    {
        testMap.put("key_" + i, i);
    }
  }
 }
```

but whenever i am changing the value of loop condition to 1000000 ***(with one less number of 0)***. the code is working fine. so is there any **time constraints** to execute static block. 
i know there is **size limitation** to **64k**, but i just want to clarify that, this is happening because of this limitation or any other reason is there behind this.

Comment: Please show the full exception. My guess is that actually you're running out of memory...

Comment: What version of jdk you use?

Comment: You might want to use `-Xmx2048m` to try to run with a larger heap...

Comment: I am executing it in eclipse and java version is 1.6.0_45. and for other case it is working. for this case one pop-up is coming "could not find main class : testPF.TestStatic. program will exit". and also i am not getting any stack trace!!!

Comment: @Vitaly: To give it a lot more memory to play with.

Comment: @Prashant: So try executing it *not* in Eclipse - from the command line you'll probably get more information.

Comment: i will try with 2048m.. ok sure :)

Comment: @JonSkeet -  (as always :P) You are right.. I just tried with `512m` and I got `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:` . `2048m` might fix it

Comment: i also had -Xmx512m so that might be solution :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are not running into limitations of static blocks. You are simply running out of heap memory. Each key and value in your map is unique and as you add a zero to the end of the loop condition you are creating 10x more of them.

You can increase the size of the Java heap with the `-Xmx` switch when you run `java`. E.g. use `-Xmx1024m` to give yourself 1Gb heap. Even that may not be enough (I haven't done the calculation!) but you'll soon find out.

Comment: it needs more heap space than 1 GB. but whenevr i am making it 2Gb eclipse is not able to open. but might be its the fix to increase to heap space.

Comment: @Prashant - What is your RAM size?

Comment: @TheLostMind its 4GB.

Comment: @Prashant - Then eclipse should open,.Anyways, I am not sure if `1024` will be sufficient

Comment: @TheLostMind 1024 is not sufficient i am checking with 2GB.